# How does convolution operation perform in CNN?

Tags: machine-learning, deep-learning, cnn, image-classification, convolution

I know that convolution operation has the property, associative law. if I need to use multiple filters in succession and to perform this operation on multiple images, it makes sense to convolve the multiple filters into a single filter ahead of time for a computational benefit. But, I wonder if the convolution layer in CNN is really computed by convolving the multiple filters into a single filter ahead.

To be honest, I just know the reason why the convolution filter is used instead of the correlation filter.

Comment: To be honest, it is cross-correlation operation used in `CNNs` not convolution :)